# How to click an imagebutton and have it appear in a new page in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-studio

I am trying to have a series of imageButtons and when clicking one, it sends the user to a different page with that image. I can have all of the images load on the first screen, but don't know how to get the image to show up on the second screen after it has been clicked. Can anyone help me?

Comment: set an `onClickListener` on the ImageButton and in it create an intent to send the user to the second screen.

Comment: how are you loading the image in first screen

Comment: krishna, right now I just dragged the widget on the screen then went in and did the source like android:src="@drawable/picture"

Answer (score 2):

To navigate from one activity to another, in android we have `Intent` class.
We can also pass data from one activity to another through   `Intent`.

So, basically, you need to send an intent from your main activity to the second activity, so that the second activity appears. Along with the intent, you need to attach data. The data in this case is the file name of the image(Resource name).

Have a look at this code.

Your main activity with two image Buttons.

```
public class mainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageButton imageButton1;
ImageButton imageButton2;

@Override
 void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 imageButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib1);
 imageButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib2);


 imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("USE_A_CONSTANT_HERE_AS_KEY", R.drawable.img1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 });

imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("USE_A_CONSTANT_HERE_AS_KEY", R.drawable.img2);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Now the second Activity where you want the image to be shown.

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
 int resourceId = getIntent.getIntentExtra("USE_A_CONSTANT_HERE_AS_KEY",R.drawable.ic_launcher)

 imageView.setImageResource(resourceId);
 } 
}
```

Now the XML layout file of your second activity 'activity_second', is the name I gave to the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"          
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now just to clarify about, `getIntent.getIntExtra("USE_A_CONSTANT_HERE_AS_KEY",R.drawable.ic_launcher)`

the first parameter in using `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` methods in Intents   are first a key, and the second the value.

It's good to have keys declared as constants.

Comment: @user1843804 If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you set resource to your button from `drawable` folder like `R.drawable.myimage` thats what you need to do:

Make intent and put in id of your image (button image or what you need)

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),Test.class);
            in.putExtra("id", R.drawable.google);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

TestActivity class:
In this class you caching intent and make setImageResource by image "ID" from intent.

```
public class Test extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    ImageView test = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_test);

    test.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("id",R.drawable.ic_launcher));
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="studio.linkup.com.animation_view.Test">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_test" />
```

Comment: R.drawable.ic_launcher - its default value if you'll take nothing.

Comment: A few questions. First, what is getActivity()? Is that something I have to import? Second, where are you putting the imageButton.setOnClicker? Third: what are the iv_test and ic_launchers? Where do I make them if I have to make them? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: getActivity method return your activity, you may write "this" what your code in Activity class. I recommend you read more about this. Put imgae button in onCreate method main activity, also set onClickListeners there. Put you Image into drawable folder (res/drawable) and you INTEGER id of this resource path will be R.drawable.image_name. You need to have more practice ! good luck. Keep your code clean )).